# Practical details on Fizeau cogwheel experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, history

Fizeau measured the speed of light using the so-called [Fizeau-Foucault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau%E2%80%93Foucault_apparatus) apparatus.

It consists, if I understood correctly, in sending light to a long distance (in the historical experiment, more than 8 kilometers) through a cogwheel, make it bounce on a mirror and go back through the cogwheel; if the cogwheel is spinning fast enough, the light may be stopped by a tooth.

**Question:** I would like to know how he managed to set up the mirror in order to reflect the light exactly at the point he sent it.

The make my question precise: let $A$ be the point of coordinates $(0,0)$, $B$ be the point of coordinates $(D,0)$. Assume there is a mirror at $B$ such that incoming light from $A$ to $B$ is reflected with an angle $\theta$. Then when the reflected light beam hits the $\{(0,y) \ \vert \ y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, it does so at point $C$, of coordinates $(0,L\tan\theta)$.

If we make the small angle approximation $\tan \theta \sim \theta$, and assuming $L = 10km$, we see that if $C$ is at distance $10cm$ of $A$, then $\theta$ is of order $\frac{2\pi}{10000}$.

Even if the angle of the mirror can be very "finely tuned", and if a friend (located at the mirror) and I (located near the cogwheel) communicate with cellphones (what Fizeau obviously couldn't do) in order to set up the experiment, I expect us to go through a lot of trouble before getting close!

Comment: Great question. I believe at the portion of light close to the mirror, he used some lenses positioned precisely to control the angle of incidence (and reflection) of the light there. But I'm not too sure on this, just throwing a guess!